# FullStack: Have a search bar that filters the input value going through multiple keys

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I'm new at web dev, currently developing a full-stack MVP on European capitals. In the main page where all capitals are listed, I wanted to add a search bar where one could filter by multiple keys (capital, country or spoken language) at once. This is the current code that I have in my index.js (not working, of course):

```
/* GET capitals by name, country or language */
router.get(`?${dynamicKey}=${dynamicValue}`, async (req, res) => {
  const { dynamicKey } = req.params;
  const { dynamicValue } = req.query;

  try {
    const results = await db(`SELECT * FROM capital WHERE ${dynamicKey} LIKE "%${dynamicValue}%";`);
    res.send(results.data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

When adding an input in the search bar (that's either a capital name, country or language), the expected outcome is a list of all capitals in which that value applies to. Of course, when one searches by capital name or country, the list will only have one component. However, when searching by language, the list might have more than one result. For instance, when searching "german", the outcome should contain Berlin, Vienna, Luxembourg... but when searching "spanish", it should only return Madrid.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to everyone that helped out! Here's the final code I used so that everything works now, in case it helps to anyone in the future:

```
/* GET all capitals or filtering */
router.get("/capitals", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.search) {
    console.log(req.query);
    try {
      const results = await db("SELECT * FROM capital ORDER BY id ASC;");
      res.send(results.data);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  } else {
    const search = req.query.search;
    console.log("SQL Query:", search);
  
    try {
    const query = `SELECT * FROM capital WHERE name LIKE "%${search}%" OR country LIKE "%${search}%" OR language LIKE "%${search}%" OR currency LIKE "%${search}%";`;
      const searchParam = `%${search}%`;
      const results = await db(query, [searchParam, searchParam, searchParam, searchParam]);
      res.send(results.data);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: What's your error? also what is value of ``dynamicKey`` and ``dynamicValue`` inside ``router.get(`?${dynamicKey}=${dynamicValue}``

Comment: Hi! So the the dynamicKey would be either name, country or language, and the dynamicValue would be the input in the search bar. For sure these two don't go in the router.get, but I don't know what I should add in there since the URL depends on what the search input is. I think the main error relies in here, right now in Postman all I can get is a 200 but getting all capitals back (when adding a URL like http://localhost:4000/api/capitals?language=english), instead of only those capitals whose official language is English.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a MySQL problem? What have yout ried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a fixed route for searching instead. Set the database query to use placeholders (?) for the search query. This will also help prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities. Try something like this,

```js
router.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
  const { query } = req.query

  try {
    const results = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM capital WHERE
      capital_name LIKE ? OR
      country LIKE ? OR
      spoken_language LIKE ?`,
      [`%${query}%`, `%${query}%`, `%${query}%`])

    res.send(results) // Assuming the database query returns an array of matching results
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error)
  }
})
```

The db.query function will accept an array of parameter values for the placeholders. when you make a request to /search?query=german, the server will execute a query to retrieve all matching capital cities where the capital name, country, or spoken language is like 'german'. The same logic applies to any other search query.
If the database table is large and using the same search term to match against multiple columns seems less efficient, you can try something like this,

```js
router.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
  const { query, searchIn } = req.query

  const validSearchColumns = ['capital_name', 'country', 'spoken_language']

  const dynamicKey = validSearchColumns.includes(searchIn) ? searchIn : null
  const dynamicValue = dynamicKey ? query : null

  if (!dynamicKey || !dynamicValue) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid search criteria.')
    return
  }

  try {
    const results = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM capital WHERE ${dynamicKey} LIKE ?`, [`%${dynamicValue}%`])
    res.send(results)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error)
  }
})
```